# IPhone Navigation-Based Application Model

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am making a Navigation-Based Application for the IPhone and I start off with a big list of names (about 100) and I was wondering what would be the quickest and most efficient way to alter the content according to what name the user tapped on in the list.

Right now I change the content according to what the title is like this:

```
NSString *comparisonString = @"Bill Clinton";
NSString *comparisonString2 = @"Bob Dole";
 if (self.title == comparisonString) {
  NSString *alterString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"He is a democrat from North Carolina "];
  [appDelegate setModelData:alterString];
 }
 else if (self.title == comparisonString2) {
  NSString *alterString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"He was born into a family in New York City... "];        
  [appDelegate setModelData:alterString];
 }
```

would this be the best way to do this? Seems like a lot of code would be repeated. I am brand new to Objective-C and developing for the IPhone, any advice will help me. Thank you!

Comment: there is no formatting going on in your stringWithFormat? is that a typo??

Comment: No I'm not really sure what I'm doing :) Before, this code included the Title in the alterString. Perhaps that's why its like this? I started with this Tutorial: http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written so far in those two conditions is equivalent to this (with no if statement):

```
NSString *alterString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Content for %@!", self.title];
[appDelegate setModelData:alterString];
```

Hope that helps.

All you are doing is changing that same part of the string in both the if and else statements (and presumably more else statements later)

**EDIT**

ok, looking now at the edited question, you basically have a look up table now. So self.title is the key and you want to use that to lookup another string.

One way to do this is to create a plist with a dictionary that maps each name to a string. Then load that plist and look up the name from there. Something like this:

```
NSDictionary* people = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToThePlist];
NSString *content = [people objectForKey:name];
```

(BTW, right now you are using '==' for string comparison, you want to use -[NSString isEqualToString:] for that in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i'm going to make the content change according to the name :)

Comment: Well, then you'll have to add more information to the question. What I wrote does exactly what your code does, but without the if/else statements. The alterString does vary along with the comparison string, no matter what the comparison string is.

Comment: Well I haven't all the content yet because I was hoping there would be an alternate way to do this. Edited the question to make clearer.

Comment: Ah, ok, now you're asking something different. I'll edit my answer as well.